# Difference between greater<> vs greater<int> vs greater<>( ) vs greater( ) in C++?

Tags: c++, comparator

I am a beginner in C++ . I encountered the use of "greater" comparator. I know about its application in places like sort(), priority_queue etc.
I just want someone to ELABORATELY explain the difference between
**greater<>** vs **greater** vs **greater<>()** vs **greater()** .
I am unable to find a definitive answer anywhere.

**EDIT** **1** : My question just was to get a general and better understanding of the "under-the-hood" mechnaics of these functions. I did get some useful information on websites like cppreference but couldn't find the difference between all four simultaneously.

**EDIT 2** : I found this comment particularly useful.

> As for OP's question, I think greater<> would be used if you wanted to create the object and store it, like greater<> func, greater would be the equivelent used before C++14 or if you do not want the types deduced, greater<>() would be used to pass into a function without storing an object after C++14, and greater() would be used to pass into a function without storing an object after C++17.

Thanks to @Colon D

Can someone confirm the abovementioned ? Or just explain more on the same ?

Comment: do you know what a template is? It is impossible to answer your question without assuming that you do. Even then the question is rather broad

Comment: What part of this article don't you understand? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/ (this is a sincere question)

Comment: @Dai Just a suggestion, but I prefer linking to cppreference instead, it's higher quality, and has fewer mistakes.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't really get what std::greater is, I've overloaded the `>` operator before, is it similar to that? It seems to call that, but I don't know why you wouldn't just use `lhs > rhs` directly.

Comment: Also with the default templated parameter being `void`, I do not see how you can compare two `void`s.

Comment: Ah, this page here says why you would use the object over `lhs > rhs`. It is so that you can pass it into a function: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/10/29/stdless-and-its-modern-evolution/

Comment: It also explains why the default parameter is `void`, which is so that you can just pass in `std::less<>{}`

Comment: @ColonD `>` isn't a value (nor does it decay to one). You can't pass it as an argument

Comment: As for OP's question, I think `greater<>` would be used if you wanted to create the object and store it, like `greater<> func`, `greater<int>` would be the equivelent used before C++14 or if you do not want the types deduced, `greater<>()` would be used to pass into a function without storing an object after C++14, and `greater()` would be used to pass into a function without storing an object after C++17.

Comment: @ColonD please don't answer in comments. If you think the question can be asnwered you should vote to reopen and then write an answer

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have been told in the past not to post an answer if I am not sure about it, so since I only think that is the answer I posted it as a comment. Nor do I have the priviledge to reopen the question.

Comment: @ColonD what would be the correct course of action is debatable. The problem with answer in comment is that there is no mechanics in place for review. Answers can be downvoted, comments not. Hence, espceically when not certain an answer is better than a comment. Nevermind, just saying...

Comment: @idclev463035818 that's ok, I appreciate your advise and will use it when I can in the future